# UIWebView in IOS 8 tables are not showing correctly

Tags: macos, ipad, ios8

we recently upgraded to IOS 8 (and compiled the application).

we saw that tables with text are not showing well anymore (we use UIWebView).

did anyone encounter this? is this a known issue or a bug?

this is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString* fullPath = @"/Users/deployment/Downloads/table-2.ppt";
[_viewWeb loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath] MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you try with WKWebView for IOS8.

Comment: @Naveenkumar no, but changing a UI view cannot be approved currently.. we want to first know if this is a bug in IOS8 and see if somehow it can be fixed

Comment: No one encountered it :(?

Comment: Can you please share your code... So I will get more clarification about this issue and try to fixed.

Comment: @Naveenkumar which part? i'm not doing anything special.. just using UIWebView

Comment: HTML link or code you showing table in webview

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried this code...?

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,10.0,300,300)];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
NSString *ppt = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"ppt"];
NSURL *pptURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ppt];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pptURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

If this code also not worked with your ppt file. Please share your ppt file too. This code working in my case. May be some issue with presentation file.

Comment: Nope, not working in IOS8. only works in IOS7.

images: [link](http://imgur.com/AgiHS6R,J6DIKZk)

ppt: [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=64140756963681922706)


it happens at every ppt with tables